# Strange behavior of java.util.ArrayList and java.util.LinkedList when removing elements in for-each loop

Tags: list, arraylist, foreach, linked-list, java-8

The following snippet of code doesn't throw a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` but if I try to remove any other element I get the (expected).

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("0");
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");

for (String el : list) {
    if (el.equals("2")) {
        list.remove(el);
    }
}
```

Things are getting more interesting if I use `java.util.LinkedList` instead of `java.util.ArrayList` where the same behavior also occurs for the last element.

This behavior occurs because of the check in java.util.ArrayList:L846.

The JDK version I use is:

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

Is this valid?

Comment: What do you mean `Is this valid?`?

Comment: I mean if this is an expected behavior or a bug, since this happens for specific elements

Comment: @Tunaki I ran the code, it does not throw the exception. Its strange

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), you cannot rely on that exception being thrown. Unfortunately, the runtime can't detect all silly mistakes the programmer is making... :)

Comment: @Tunaki this looks more like a bug to me rather than a relaxed specification. Obviously, changing != to < would have solved this bug for the ArrayList

Comment: It is not a bug, it is clearly specified that you cannot rely on that exception being thrown.